Tracker-extract-3 crashed on ubuntu 24.04
I put my computer to sleep mode but when I opened it it showed me a frozen login screen with the old time.
I tried everything from holding the power up button to restarting my graphic card to Ctrl+Alt+Delete but nothing worked except for the REISUB method.
After it opened, an error window popped up stating that Ubuntu has experienced an internal error with the title:
Tracker-extract-3 crashed with SIGSIEV in__strcmp_avx2()
Does anyone know the cause of this error?

not a Ubuntu resource but this Arch post may hold the clue you are looking for.
